# Class not found when l run php artisan token:generate 1 in laravel so l can get a bearer token for Swagger UI Auth

Tags: laravel, swagger

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\User;

class TokenCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'token:generate {id}';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $id = $this->argument('id');
        $user = User::find($id);

        \Auth::setUser($user);

        $console = new ConsoleOutput();

        $console->writeln($user->createToken('admin')->accessToken);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the user details in Swagger UI but I'm getting an error when l run "php artisan token: generate 1" to generate a token for authorization in swagger UI

l'm new to laravel and this is the error I'm getting

Class 'App\Console\Commands\ConsoleOutput' not found

at C:\xampp\htdocs\Event\ems\backend\app\Console\Commands\TokenCommand.php:29
25▕         $user = User::find($id);
26▕
27▕         \Auth::setUser($user);
28▕
➜  29▕         $console = new ConsoleOutput();
30▕
31▕         $console->writeln($user->createToken('admin')->accessToken);
32▕     }
33▕ }

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\Event\ems\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
App\Console\Commands\TokenCommand::handle()

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\Event\ems\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:40
Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported the `ConsoleOutput` class. Add the below line on the top of your class file.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
```

Comment: Thank you  for the help